# How to read Column Properties from SSAS tabular DB

Tags: c#, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

I was reading about [Column Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479566(v=sql.110).aspx). I want to know how can I using C# read column properties from the SSAS tabular database?

Comment: After a bit of Googleing i found this:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdDataReader(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @DaImTo: This class actually `Provides a means of reading a forward-only result set that is obtained by running a command, and can be used to access analytical data sources.`. Which means I need to execute a command before I can use it. In my case, I need to read cube information & there is no need to execute the command. Thank you for reply.